# Virtualized Linux firewall as router on the stick for cisco switch

Tags: linux, cisco, virtual-machines, vlan

I have got:

```
Linux(virtual maschine on esxi)  <---trunk--->  cisco Switch.
```

On virtual maschine vSwitch setup:

```
VLAN ID 4095 Enables trunking on port group (VGT Mode)
```

LINUX interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address xxx.xx.xx.x
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway xxx.xx.xx.z

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.63.254
    netmask 255.255.192.0

auto eth1.10
iface eth1.10 inet static
    address 192.168.63.254
    netmask 255.255.192.0

auto eth1.99
iface eth1.99 inet static
    address 10.50.50.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

modprobe 8021q is enabled. When i do :

```
cat /proc/net/vlan/config
```

i see:

```
VLAN Dev name    | VLAN ID
Name-Type: VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
eth1.10        | 10  | eth1
eth1.99        | 99  | eth1
```

so i suppose vlans are active.

cisco switch setup on port connected to linux:

```
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk native vlan 1
```

Client connected to switch on port in vlan 10:

```
ip 192.168.3.57
gateway 192.168.63.254
```

Cannot ping 192.168.63.254 - the gateway for this vlan. Do i need to enable something more or config is wrong ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the same IP address in two separate broadcast domains. Remove `192.168.63.254` from `eth1`

Once your routing is sorted, I'll assume you have the firewall off, or appropriate services allowed in. Start with the firewall off, then if required, turn it on once things are otherwise working.

You may need to set `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` so the Linux system routes between connected subnets.

Comment: i have forwarding enabled. I will remove ip from main interface - hope it helps me.

Comment: You were right i had to set up another subnet on main interface.